# Defining constant for screen width

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I have a constant defined with screen width to 320. This is being used at multiple places in my code. I have to change this to take value from current device and I do not want to touch all these places. So, I want to define a constant for this with value:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width

#define kScreenWidth [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width
```

But it is giving me lot of compilation errors. Any clue?

Comment: Can we see what the actual compilation errors are?

Comment: do you include UIScreen.h before the def?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width
```